# Irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: number-theory

The standard proof by contradiction, of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ (linked here: http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/q1.html) just say's that for every irreducible fraction $\frac p q$ that we take, we can prove that $p$ and $q$ can be reduced further by division by two. But we can say that $p$ and $q$ are such that $p = 2^m k$ and $q = 2^n l$ such that $m,n \rightarrow \infty$.

This would mean that $p$ and $q$ are infinitely large, but why can't they be so? Why can't we say that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number such that as $p$ and $q$ keep getting larger and larger, we get a better and better resolution, and in the limit, we get $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Numbers don’t move. If you’re using decimal representation, a number is described by a particular sequence of digits. For whole numbers like $p$ and $q$, this means specifying beforehand how many digits there are, and then saying what each of these digits is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion is all about what a number is. The point is that "real numbers are finite". Remember that infinity is not a number. It sounds like you are saying that $\sqrt{2}$ should be equal to $p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are increasing. What do you mean by that. $p$ and $q$ are integers and they don't change. Mathematical objects are like plants that change over time.

Saying that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number has a very precise definition. It means that the is the quotient of two integers. And assuming this, one can get a contradiction which proves that the assumption made was wrong and hence $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of standard proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.  Here's another (in some sense equivalent) proof that more thoroughly highlights the issue: suppose $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.  Find positive integers $p, q$ so that $\sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q}$.  Squaring, we obtain $2 q^2 = p^2$.  So $2$ divides $p$, and, in the standard fashion, we also deduce that $2$ divides $q$.  Let $p' = \frac{p}{2}$ and $q' = \frac{q}{2}$.  Then $p', q'$ are positive integers such that $\frac{p'}{q'} = \sqrt{2}$.

Thus we can actually construct a decreasing sequence of positive integers $p = p_0 > p_1 > ...$ and $q = q_0 > q_1 > ...$ so that $\frac{p_j}{q_j} = \sqrt{2}$.  In fact, we'll have $q_j = \frac{q}{2^j}$ and $p_j = \frac{p}{2^j}$.  The contradiction is that, of course, for some $j$, $p_j$ and $q_j$ are not integers.

The contradiction isn't that we can't find successively smaller numbers whose ratio is $\sqrt{2}$.  That's easy, and it's a consequence of standard properties of the reals.  But the integers are very particular numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider all expressions for the square root as $a/b$, with positive integers $a$ and $b$ among them  there must  a UNIQUE expression with least value for $b$. Now the usual arguments say $a$ and $b$ have 2 as common factor leading to a smaller expression after cancelling 2, contradicting the minimality of $b$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that we can terminate the proof by deducing the contradiction that $\,p,q>0\,$ are divisible by arbitrarily large integers. One of the "features" of proofs by contradiction is that there are often many different ways to deduce a contradiction. Alternatively we could deduce that $\,2 = 1\,$ because $1$ is the only natural $\,n\,$ such that $\,n^k\mid p>0\,$ for unbounded $\,k.\,$

It is important to keep in mind that these deductions take place in a *hypothetical universe* obtained by assuming that $\sqrt 2\,$ is rational (which is false). The conclusions obtained by deductions in this hypothetical universe need not hold true in the actual universe of natural numbers (esp. any deductions that depend upon the false hypothesis).

Another example: if Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes is presented as a proof by contradiction then one form of the argument deduces that $\,1+p_1\cdots p_n\,$ is a prime. But this does not imply that this true in $\,\Bbb N\,$ since the argument is founded on the false hypothesis that there are only finitely many primes $\,p_1,\ldots,p_n.\, $ In fact, $\,1+2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot 13 = 30031 =59\cdot 509.$